# Non linear chart Y-axis EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Is it possible to create a chart in Excel in which the Y-axis goes up by order of magnitude rather than linear.

so rising like

```
1,10,100,1000....
```

Or even doubling

```
1,2,4,8,16,32.....
```

Rather than

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Or

```
10,20,30,40,50,60.....
```

Like the chart below ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change vertical axis to log scale, and also change the base of log.

[image]